# signalr: how to update all clients having specific cookie value?

Tags: mysql, .net, sockets, signalr

We have an API exposed from where our partner networks can send loan offers and this offer gets saved in our MySQL database. For example, they send offer as:

```
/api/loanoffer/
{
  "mobile": "+23498234",
  "offer": "$ 23443"
}
```

We want to show this loan offer immediately to all our connected clients (by matching the mobile number of the offer and connected client).

We save mobile information of the users in client cookies. How can we relay this information from mysql database to all the connected clients? It would be best if we can give solution keeping web, ios and android client in mind.

Answer (score 0):

When you get this information and store it in Cookie, store some ID with it as well like username or mobile number which is unique or MD5 the mobile number. Ideally store that on server with connecton ID. When you get it back then send it to that connection ID. However if you cant store that on server then do this

When you need to send that message out then send that **message out to all clients**. Pass the MD5 mobile number and on client side if it matches the cookie value of MD5 client mobile number then show notification otherwise stay calm and carry on.